# Write an Excel file with C#

Tags: c#, excel, dll

I need to write an Excel file with C#,
and I dont know how..

Can anyone give me a library that can do something like that?:

```
Cell(1, 1) = "16.3.2013"; //the first number is the column, the second number is the row
Cell(1, 2) = "Firt name";
Cell(2, 2) = "Last name";
Cell(3, 2) = "Passed/Failed";
```

Thanks anyway :)